# Hiding soft keyboard android will cause error in older API levels?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have used this line of code to hide soft keyboard. Will it cause error on older API levels?
I am targeting API level 11 to 17. 
Or will it cause error if device does not have soft keyboard?

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it cause error on older API levels?

To answer this question, you need to read the documentation for your classes and method calls. Each class and method indicates the API level in which in was introduced, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: API level in upper right corner of methods]

For each of your method calls:

- [`getWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow%28%29) was introduced in API level 1
- [`setSoftInputMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode%28int%29) was introduced in API level 3
- [`WindowManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) and its [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) were introduced in API level 1
- [`SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN) was introduced in API level 3

So no, your code will not cause an error due to the Android version on devices from API level 11 to 17.

> Or will it cause error if device does not have soft keyboard?

I have not heard of any devices that don't have a soft keyboard, but I believe that the value you set will simply be ignored if there is no soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```